# Issues with downgrading or finding Sql server with certain version

Tags: sql-server

I am currently having some issues related to
the sql server version which is running on a 
different envriroment.  I don't have directly access to production, 
thus I need to recreate the sceanario on local.

I am currently runningn a higher version sql server than on production, 
An thus looking for a way in which i can downgrade my current instance, or just have one running on the side, with the lower version.

It just seems impossible to find a sql server install download for the version 12.0.5590.1

Comment: This is off topic for Stack Overflow, but which edition are you after, Express or Developer?

Comment: any would be fine

Comment: [Google - Download and install sql server 2014 (I'm feeling lucky)](https://www.google.com/search?q=Download+and+install+sql+server+2014&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b) -> [Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=42299). Search engines are your friend.

Comment: i did, but no server is being installed? It is still the same version 14.x

Comment: What do you mean no server is being installed and it's still the same?  SQL Server 2014 is version 12.x. 2017 is version 14, and I didn't link you to a 2017 download.